# Defining an accumulation of an inexact differential

Tags: calculus

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential)

> An inexact differential is commonly defined as a differential form $\delta x$ where there is no corresponding function x such that: $x=\int \delta x.$

---

However, is there anything from stopping us from defining a function

$$x(C) = \int_C \delta x.$$

Where $C$ is a specified path over which we accumulate the inexact differential $\delta x$.

---

If anyone is familiar with thermodynamics, I'm asking if we could define the total heat change over a thermodynamic process as

$$Q(C) = \int_C \delta q.$$

This would be useful when thinking about how the heat along a fluid streamline effects the enthalpy

$$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla} h = \vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla} Q + \frac{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla} p}{\rho}.$$

Where now $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla}$ is the gradient along the specific path, i.e., the streamline. So then we have

$$\textrm{d} h = \delta q + \frac{\textrm{d} p}{\rho},$$

Along the streamline, which is a fundamental relationship of thermodynamics.

Comment: Sure. The point is that it depends on the actual path, not merely the endpoints of the path. (It would also make more sense to call it $\Delta x(C)$ or something.)